# Find and replace with sequential numbers

Tags: replace, notepad++, findandmodify

I am trying to figure out how to perform a find and replace with sequential data. An example of the data:

Filename "voice/voice_001.ogg"

Filename "voice/voice_002.ogg"

I wish to 'move' by using find and replace to:

"voice/voice_001.ogg" Filename

"voice/voice_002.ogg" Filename

Is there anyway to do this? I have been trying to do so by using notepad++ but can't get it done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex mode find/replace:

**Find:**

```
(Filename) ("[^\s]*")
```

**Replace:**

```
$2 $1
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! Worked like a charm :)